# Avoid stemming of Acronyms?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, text-mining

I am using the `pattern_capture` filter to preserve all the acronyms

```
PUT test_index/_settings
{
  "index.analysis.filter": {
    "acronym_en_EN": {
      "type": "pattern_capture",
      "patterns": [
        "(?:[a-zA-Z]\\.)+", 
        "((?:[a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z])",
        "((?:[a-zA-Z]\\.)+[s]$)",
        "((?:[a-zA-Z]\\.)+[s][\\.]$)"
        ],
      "preserve_original": true
    }
  }
}
```

But i noticed that acronyms that end with `s` or `s.` are stemmed as there is one stemmer filter also attached to the analyzer. The regular expressions in the filter above for handling `s` are also not working.

I test the output using this

```
GET test_index/_analyze?tokenizer=standard&filters=lowercase,acronym_en_EN,apostrophe,porter_stemmer_en_EN&text=u.s.a. u.s. s.w.a.t u.t.
```

this gives me

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "u.s.a",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 5,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "u.",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "u.",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "s.w.a.t",
         "start_offset": 12,
         "end_offset": 19,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "u.t",
         "start_offset": 20,
         "end_offset": 23,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there any way I can preserve the acronyms ending with `s` so that for `u.s.` or `u.s` I don't get `u.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is supported out of the box. I believe the way to do this is to teach the `pattern_capture` filter how to mark its captures as `keyword` tokens ala the `keyword_marker` filter.

Honestly you could probably hack something together with two `pattern_replace` token filters - one on either side of the stemmer. Just slap a `$` or something on the front of the acronyms and rip it off on the other side.

Comment: Adding a `$` seems to be a good idea. But most of the examples related to `pattern_replace` are about replacing the matched term with an empty string. Is there a way I can replace it with the same match term??

Comment: Capture groups should work ala [appendReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: I used `#` as the delimiter for those acronyms. I think it should work. Thanks for the suggestion.